# Tomcat doesn't see my servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, get, request

I'm working on ubuntu server 14.04 with tomcat 7 and jdk 8.
I'm new to java servlets. So I red this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm, and did the same (but not in ROOT - in TESTAPP), but when I try http://localhost:8080/TESTAPP/HelloWorld i get 404 error.
Directory hierarchy:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/TESTAPP/
|
-- index.html
-- META_INF/
-- WEB_INF/
   |
----- web.xml
----- classes/
      |
-------- HelloWorld.java
-------- HelloWorld.class
```

index.html:

```
<h1>TESTAPP</h1>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="TESTAPP" 
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  private String message;

  public void init() throws ServletException
  {
      // Do required initialization
      message = "Hello World";
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
  }

  public void destroy()
  {
      // do nothing.
  }
}
```

then i did

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar
javac HelloWorld.java
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

catalina.out: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5SM3vatg

so then in browseer (or with curl)
for http://localhost:8080/TESTAPP i get OK
for http://localhost:8080/TESTAPP/HelloWorld i get NOT FOUND.

---

So where is my mistake?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The directory where Tomcat deploys web applications is named "webapps" and not "webapp" as appears on your directory hierarchy.

Comment: You are right. I made mistake when was writing this post. I edited my post.

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the Tomcat log? It should be in /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out in your case

Comment: I'm not sure what is relevant portion, but i removed catalina.out and restarted tomcat7 so this file appeared again. And i added file to the end of the post.

Comment: Right, it looks like your app is being correctly deployed. Did you try to access the URL of the webapp before collecting the logs? They show no sign of a request being received. Another suggestion would be to try to add a slash at the end of the URL, for this is a known nuisance depending of the server configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately slash didn't solve my problem. And what did you mean - to access URL before collecting log? Logs i get when i start tomcat.

Comment: You type the URL that gives you the problem in a browser, then look at the Tomcat logs to see what (if any) error appears.